# Is it safe to clone to the same git directory

Tags: git

For example, first there is no `test` directory, I `git clone`:

```
`git clone git@github.com:test/test.git test`
```

Then after some push/pull, I do it again:

```
`git clone git@github.com:test/test.git test`
```

Will the second clone damage the local test repo?

REASON:

I `clone` in a one-time script, which is supposed to run one time, ideally. But if it fails, or another reason, it might be run multiple times, so `clone` will be run multiple times too. If it's not ok, I will do an `rm -rf test` first.

Comment: It won't work, as the directory is not empty. Try it...

Comment: Why do you even need to clone again? You already have the references just `fetch` from origin in case required.

Comment: because i do `clone` in a one-time script, this script is supposed to run one time, ideally, but if it fails, or on other reason, it might be ran multiple times, so `clone` will be ran multiple times too. if its no ok, i will do a `rm -rf test` first.

Comment: @Sato Put things into action `if` it does not fail and other things(retrying) `if` it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can read in the git docs:

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory

and

> Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty

In your case, cloning into an already cloned directory just won't work.

In your script you can handle/test the return code of git command and perform proper actions if git clone fails or not.

Replying to your question: yes, it's safe to run git clone multiple time. The repository won't be damaged.